# ¿Cómo detectar el navegador utilizado en un móvil?

Tags: php, javascript, programación-móvil, navegador-web

Necesito saber con que navegador se abre mi página web desde un dispositivo móvil.
En especial necesitaría saber si se está abriendo desde el navegador por defecto de Android (el de la bola del mundo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como aportación a la respuesta de @Muriano:

Si se usa [**`get_browser`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-browser.php) hay que tener en cuenta la siguiente nota indicada en el Manual de PHP:

> Para que esto funcione, la configuración de browscap en `php.ini` debe
>   apuntar a la ubicación correcta del archivo `browscap.ini` en su
>   sistema. `browscap.ini` no está incluido con PHP, pero se pude encontrar
>   un archivo actualizado aquí [» php_browscap.ini](http://browscap.org/). Mientras que
>   `browscap.ini` contiene información sobre muchos navegadores, recae en
>   el usuario la actualización para mantener la bases de datos vigente.
>   El formato del archivo se explica por sí solo.

Si se quiere un función sencilla para detectar el navegador. Se puede usar la siguiente (tomada de las [contribuciones en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-browser.php#119332)). Está actualizada a Mayo del 2016 y posteriores actualizaciones serían relativamente fáciles, agregando una línea con `elseif ...`:

```
<?php

// Función:

function get_browser_name($user_agent)
{
    if (strpos($user_agent, 'Opera') || strpos($user_agent, 'OPR/')) return 'Opera';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Edge')) return 'Edge';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Chrome')) return 'Chrome';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Safari')) return 'Safari';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Firefox')) return 'Firefox';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'MSIE') || strpos($user_agent, 'Trident/7')) return 'Internet Explorer';

    return 'Other';
}

// Uso:

echo get_browser_name($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano como puedo utilizar el `get_browser` he descargado eso archivos desde aquella página que has citado, esos archivos descargados donde se ubican, como se llaman para que funcione... [He implementado el ejemplo que has dado en su respuesta, en mi código, en una pregunta aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/187557/cómo-crear-un-contador-de-referencia-usando-php-mysqli) pero me interesa sobre el uso de `get_browser` me parece interesante.

Answer (score 1):

Con la función [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-browser.php)

```
<?php
     echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

     $navegador = get_browser(null, true);
     print_r($navegador);
 ?>
```

Resultado:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3
>
> Array
>   (
>       [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0.9.*$
>       [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
>       [parent] => Firefox 0.9
>       [platform] => WinXP
>       [browser] => Firefox
>       [version] => 0.9
>       [majorver] => 0
>       [minorver] => 9
>       [cssversion] => 2
>       [frames] => 1
>       [iframes] => 1
>       [tables] => 1
>       [cookies] => 1
>       [backgroundsounds] =>
>       [vbscript] =>
>       [javascript] => 1
>       [javaapplets] => 1
>       [activexcontrols] =>
>       [cdf] =>
>       [aol] =>
>       [beta] => 1
>       [win16] =>
>       [crawler] =>
>       [stripper] =>
>       [wap] =>
>       [netclr] =>
>   )

Lo que ocurre con ella es que es MUY lenta. En su lugar te recomiendo una librería de terceros como https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser (El desarrollo no es mio, pero la he usado en múltiples ocasiones y cumple las espectativas)

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias!