# Problemas para obtener el navegador $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] con PHP7

Tags: php, navegador-web

Quiero obtener el navegador del usuario que visita mi sitio web para ofrecer una mejor experiencia de usuarios a mis visitantes.

Pero resulta que mediante un código que encontré investigando por Internet, logre obtener solo el Chrome y el Firefox de los usuarios, para obtener el **Brave**, **OperaMini** y el **Microsoft Edge** no me esta funcionando. solo me funciona **Firefox** y **Google Chrome**

Cuando visito mi pagina web desde OperaMini o desde el navegador Brave, me dice que estoy visitando desde Google Chrome cuando no es así, por favor necesito ayuda.

**Código para obtener el navegador:**

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '83.0.4103.116') != FALSE) {
    echo 'Está usando Google Chrome.<br />';
}elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '30.3061') != FALSE){
    echo 'Está usando Opera Mini.<br />';   
}elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], '5.0') != FALSE){
    echo 'Está usando Mozilla Firefox.<br />';
}elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') != FALSE){
    echo 'Está usando Internet Explore.<br />';
}
```

Si necesitan mas información, por favor no le den mala reputación a mi pregunta, solo haganmelo saber para dar mas información y encontrar solución a este problema.

*Feliz resto del día.*

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar [`get_browser`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-browser.php)?

Comment: La verdad es que no lo he intentado, porque estoy trabajando con PHP básico, php estructurado, pero ahora mismo voy a investigar un poco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en los valores que usas para comparar, tales como `83.0.4103.116`, `30.3061` o `5.0`.

En esta [Nota de contribución](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-browser.php#119332) del Manual de PHP se indican otros valores de comparación.

He creado esta función en base a esos valores y funciona perfectamente:

```
function getBrowser($infoUA) {
    /*
        Array con valores asociativos a buscar
        para identificar el navegador
        En futuras evoluciones podría ser necesario
        agregar nuevos identificadores según los UA
    */
    $mBrowsers=array(
                        'Opera'    =>'Opera',
                        'OPR/'     =>'Opera',
                        'Edge'     =>'Edge', 
                        'Chrome'   =>'Chrome', 
                        'Safari'   =>'Safari', 
                        'Firefox'  =>'Firefox', 
                        'MSIE'     =>'Internet Explorer', 
                        'Trident/7'=>'Internet Explorer', 
                    );
    
    /*
        Se buscará alguno de los términos
        que haya arrojado el UA
        Si lo encuentra, retornará el valor del array
        que indica qué navegador es
        De lo contrario, retornará "Otro"
    */
    foreach($mBrowsers as $k=>$v) {
        if (stripos($infoUA,$k) !== false) return $v;
    }
    return "Otro";
}
```

Quise usar un array para asociar los valores, para evitar los ´elseif´ y porque el código así es más mantenible en el caso de necesitar agregar nuevos identificadores.

### Modo de uso

Obtendrías los datos del UA mediante:

```
$infoUA=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Y pasarías ese dato a la función:

```
echo getBrowser($infoUA);
```

Como ha dicho @Marcos en su comentario, puedes usar `get_browser()`, pero [hay algunas cosas que conviene saber antes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74992/29967).